# A Group of order $p^n$ is not simple

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a group that $|G|=p^n$, with $n \geq 2$ and $p$ prime.

Show that G is not simple.

I know that, if $G$ is not abelian, then $Z(G) \not= G$ and $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with $|Z(G)|= p^m >1$ and $m <n$.
And since $Z(G) \lhd G$, we have G being not simple.

But what if G is abelian? That proof would not be possible.

Comment: Hint: the problem is even easier if $G$ is abelian!

Comment: If $G$ is abelian of order $p^n$ with $n\ge 2$, then every subgroup of order $p$  is normal. By Cauchy's theorem there is such a subgroup.

Comment: Dean's answer in the duplicate deals with the abelian case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is Abelian, then all subgroups are normal so it's enough to find a non-trivial proper subgroup. If $G$ is order $p^n$ with $n\ge2$, then there is an element $x$ of order $p$. If you let $H=\langle x\rangle$, the subgroup generated by $x$, then $\vert H\vert=p$, so $H$ is a non-trivial proper subgroup.